# How to write in a "sticky" way

Tags: drawing

Does anyone know how to write/draw like in this video? https://youtu.be/L4faHv_iRtU

The way he writes letters (e.g. e, sin, x...) seems "sticky" and I really want to know how to achieve this technique.

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of the drawing program. In Photoshop its called *stroke smoothing* what it does it makes your brush lag a bit but the computer can now average your results.*

* This isn't a digital only thing. If you look at people drawing pin striping they use brushes with very long bristles this achieves the same kind of stabilisation.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, it seems not to be what I'm looking for. I've tried some "stroke smoothing" apps and it just doesn't feel like the way he writes in the video. Pay attention to the letter "d" at o:25, the mouse went far up then down and the resulted stroke was a short line. It feels like drawing lines in paint but the stroke begin to "freeze" gradually from the start till the end.